# Parsing XmlNodeList directly to string when assigning

Tags: c#, parsing, xml-parsing

So I am trying to parse an XML file to a class and I would want to make my life a bit easier by parsing the value from Xml directly to String

I have been looking to try and find a solution but I probably cannot phrase the question well enough to find it out.

```
XmlNodeList screeningRequestID = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ScreeningRequestID");
            ScreeningRequestID = Convert.ToString(screeningRequestID[0].InnerText);
```

It works fine how it is, but I am pretty sure you can do it in a shorter way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.Linq` to shorten the code as below

```
    var value = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ScreeningRequestID").Cast<XmlNode>().First().InnerText;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks to you comment I actually found exactly what I was looking for
```ScreeningRequestID = Convert.ToString(doc.GetElementsByTagName("ScreeningRequestUniqueID")[0].InnerText);```